# Loop keeps going after being carried out

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break, python-3.3

```
def Help(string):
    while True:
        if string == 'Manifest':
            return Manifest()
            break
        elif string == 'Intent':
            return Intent()
            break
        else:
            print('The options available are: \n')
            for i in andHelp:
                print(i)
            print('Type Q to Quit \n')
            x = input('What option do you choose: ')
            print('\n')
            if x == 'Q':
                break
            else:
                Help(x)
```

How come if it goes into the else statement it will keep looping?
for example:

"The options available are:

Intent

Manifest

Type Q to Quit

What option do you choose: " <-- this will keep coming up aswell as the function I choose.

Comment: How is the method entered in the first place?

Comment: Because it's a constant, infinite loop.

Comment: would the break not make it stop?

Comment: Did you type 'q' (little Q)? Try _if x.upper() == 'Q'_. Also, don't call Help() again, you already cover that in the while loop. You end up with nested calls that will keep asking the question as they unwrap.

Comment: The recursion seems unnecessary anyway. Rather than call `Help(x)`, just set `string=x` and let the loop return to the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a while loop for what you are checking. Use this instead:

```
def Help(string):
    if string == 'Manifest':
        return Manifest()
    elif string == 'Intent':
        return Intent()
    else:
        print('The options available are:\n%s\nType Q to Quit\n' % '\n'.join(andHelp))
        x = input('What option do you choose: ')
        print('\n')
        if x != 'Q':
            Help(x)
```

*note:* I modified your prints a bit to reduce extra lines that really, didn't need to be there.
*note2:* As you may see in the comments, it may be dangerous to do this recursively without a limitation because you may reach a maximum depth level.

Comment: Yea what happens when I enter `"cat pee"` 1001 times. your program explodes!

Comment: Thank you! Just a bit new to Python, so I don't see the obvious answers. :) Thanks!

Comment: @JakobBowyer I'm sorry, but this is not a mistake, it is the design. If the OP wants to limit retry attempts that is his choice, as it stands, the code does what the OP expects, to keep asking for input until 'Q' or 'Manifest' or 'Intent' are input. Regardless, constant input of `"cat pee"` will not explode anything, just be a very long annoying cycle.

Comment: @InbarRose: actually, it *will* crash, due to Python's recursion limits.  Try it yourself (although you might want to lower the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit` first, to save time.)  For this reason, recursion possibilities due to user input are usually considered a design flaw, and `while True: [...] break` loops are preferred.

Comment: @DSM You are absolutely correct, the thought had not crossed my mind. recursion is a fickle B****. I will add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem is due to your recursion not actually returning the inner frame's value, but eliminating the recursion seems a more straightforward solution.

What's goofy about this is doing a recursion inside a loop. Both the recursion and the loop serve the same purpose: To make the `option` choice keep happening until a valid option is given. So you can definitely eliminate one:

```
def Help(string):
    while True:
        if string == 'Manifest':
            return Manifest()
            break
        elif string == 'Intent':
            return Intent()
            break
        else:
            print('The options available are: \n')
            for i in andHelp:
                print(i)
            print('Type Q to Quit \n')
            string = input('What option do you choose: ') # Change `x` to `string` so next iteration will change behavior
            print('\n')
            if string == 'Q':
                break
```

As [Inbar Rose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053216/418413) points out, you can shorten this quite a bit with recursion, but since Python requires a recursion limit, you can make the program crash by forcing it to recur beyond that limit. So perhaps sticking with the loop is better. Anyway, you can clean it up further by having the validation of `string` be the condition of the loop itself:

```
def Help(string):
    validOptions = ('Manifest', 'Intent', 'Q')

    while string not in validOptions:
        print('The options available are: \n')
        for i in andHelp:
            print(i)
        print('Type Q to Quit \n')
        string = input('What option do you choose: ')
        print('\n')

    # Now you have a guaranteed-valid string, so you don't need this part in the loop.
    if string == 'Manifest':
        return Manifest() # No need for a 'break' after a return. It's [dead code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code)
    elif string == 'Intent':
        return Intent()
    elif string == 'Q':
        return
```

Comment: Thank You :) Always Looking For Improving Code :)